# How can I protect coupon codes in PHP against brute force?

Tags: php, mysql, coupon

I am working on a project where I have to generate coupon codes for the users which they can use during the registration process. How should I protect the coupon codes against the brute force attack or any other kind of attack?

My coupon codes are generated in this format: "XYZ-TC2MSD-ABC". They have a validity of 1 day.

Comment: Is it not protected by the registration, the user logs in and then uses the code, therefore the brute force attack would not be possible on that code?  Or am I thinking about it the wrong way?

Comment: I would say the same way that you protect your registration form against spammers. BTW, that's a lot of permutations to brute force in a day. If you're worried, you could limit the number of tries per session/IP address at an arbitrarily large number, or certain number of tries in an hour which normal users would never reach.

Comment: You could always use throttling or something like a captcha after three failed attempts. The fact that your coupon codes are invalid after a day is good. Note that to brute force it, the attacker needs 36^12 = around 5 quintillion attempts (4.7e18 to be exact) in the worst case so I guess you're pretty safe.

Comment: insert a `sleep` after each wrong attempt

Comment: @Loek 4.7e18 to match an exact string. There is always a chance a brute forced combination exists as a voucher within 10 tries.

Comment: note the "in the worst case". Unless OP has an average coupon count of like 5 billion at any time, the statistics are hugely in OP's favor (and even then, the chance is 0.00000001%). But indeed, you're right. Statistics are just that and an attacker might get lucky.

Comment: Rate limits and long codes.

Comment: @Philipp That's a good way to accidentally DDOS yourself, though.